# I am writing a SH Shell script in Linux RedHat. Can I use "set -x | tee > output.file"?

Tags: bash, shell, set, tee

At the beginning of my script I have the "set -x" line.  This, of course, sends all output to the screen.  This is exactly what I like so that I can see what the script is doing and fix issues along the way.  Once the script works correctly I comment out the "set -x" line.

I would like to tee the output of set -x so that I have a file to look at instead of using the display only.  Is there a way to do this?

I've tried "set -x | tee ScriptNameHere.DEBUG" and it gives me a file named ScriptNameHere.DEBUG with ZERO bytes in it... an empty file.

set -x | tee scriptname.debug
set -x | tee -a scriptname.debug

All give me a Zero byte file named scriptname.debug.

Comment: Tag bash _or_ sh, not both; they're two different languages. (Even on distros where `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `bash`, bash turns off some features when called under the `sh` name; and generally, your distro reserves the right in a future major release to replace `sh` with any other POSIX-compliant shell, so even if it's bash today, in the future it might be dash or zsh in compatibility mode, not bash at all; for Debian/Ubuntu people this has already happened).

Comment: BTW, do note that when you send some content direct to the console and other content through tee, that makes delivery (pretty much unavoidably) asynchronous, such that the traces written by `set -x` with delivery going through tee can be written to the terminal _after_ things that were written direct to the terminal are printed.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do this with sh, but you can do it with bash (as long as you aren't on the ancient version shipped by Apple).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in
  ''|[1-3].*|4.[012].*) echo "ERROR: bash 4.3 or newer required" >&2; exit 1;;
esac

exec {BASH_XTRACEFD}> >(tee -a ScriptNameHere.DEBUG >&2)
set -x
# ... other content of your script below
```

Explaining the above:

- When `exec` is passed only redirections, and not a command, it performs those redirections in the current shell.
- In bash 4.x and later, `BASH_XTRACEFD` gives the number of the file descriptor where xtrace (`set -x`) will write logs.
- Starting somewhere later in the 4.x series (4.1? 4.3?), a redirection of `{varname}>file` dynamically assigns a file descriptor number to the variable `"$varname"` of a handle writing to file `file`.
- `>(...)` is a [process substitution](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution), replaced with a filename (typically on Linux something like `/dev/fd/##` or `/proc/self/fd/##`) that, when written to, will deliver content to the program invoked by the command `...`; one for read is instead `<(...)`.

Thus, the net effect is to start a copy of `tee` in the background and attach it to a file descriptor whose number is written to `$BASH_XTRACEFD`, such that when `set -x` is later run, the logs will be written to that copy of `tee` and thereafter to the specified file.

Comment: Having the fd in a variable imposes some restrictions. Things like `echo additional trace info >&$BASH_XTRACEFD` work, but trying to close the fd with `exec $BASH_XTRACEFD>&-` terminates the shell. You have to use evil `eval`.

Comment: @MarkReed, `exec {BASH_XTRACEFD}>&-` works to close the file without `eval` -- bash added the necessary syntax to handle FDs from variables at the same time as they implemented automatic allocation. (Note the lack of a `$` in that command; leaving it out is intentional/necessary).

Comment: Ah, so. Wonder how I missed this feature. It works in Zsh and Ksh, too, FWIW.

Answer (score 1):

`set -x | whatever` or `>wherever` just sends the output of the `set -x` itself - which doesn't output anything!  It *turns on* tracing output, which comes from the shell, not any of the commands the shell runs.

You can capture it, though; just by redirecting stderr, e.g. with

```
exec 2>>trace.out
set -x
```

or, to have it go to both the screen and the file

```
exec 2> >(tee -a trace.out)
set -x
```

Comment: The OP is trying to only redirect the trace itself, though, not all of stderr; that's a job for `BASH_XTRACEFD`.

Comment: Then the bash trick in your answer seems like the way to go. Or perhaps rolling their own pseudo-xtrace with a `DEBUG` trap, so they can send it wherever they want.

Comment: _nod_, the DEBUG trap approach makes sense if they have a hard requirement to support bash 3.x.